# How to Reparent the panel when close the frame

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am creating a GUI which have a main window, which is wxFrame, on the main window there has a button. In the main window class, I have members which is a wxMiniFrame, and a wxPanel.

The scenario is when I click the button a new wxMiniFrame will be create and the Panel will be reparent to the wxMiniFrame, when the mini Frame is closed, I want the wxPanel to be reparent to the main window.

Is there any method to detect the miniframe is closed so that I can reparent the Panel?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The wxMiniFrame has a close button on the right top corner, when I click it the miniFrame will be destroy and the wxPanel will also be destroy as it current parent is the miniFrame, but I want to keep the Panel. Is it possible to hide the miniFrame instead of closing it when I click that button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling the usual `wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW` should work fine for mini frames too.

In any case, you can always do it from your `wxMiniFrame`-derived class dtor.

Comment: Is it possible to hide the miniframe instead of closing it when I click the close button on the top right corner?

Comment: I have another problem, when the mini frame is create, it always display on the top, even though I click on the main frame.